# jsonDiff in a loop for lots of files

Tags: python, json, diff

The goal is to get the difference of around 30'000 json files in 2 two folders. In both Folders their names are just numbers (1.json, 2.json etc.). So basically get the diff of the two folders.

I'm using the jsonDiff module to get the difference which works fine for single files but i haven't found a way to use the module in a loop.

```
f = open("/folder1/1.json")
fe = open("/folder2/1.json")
jyson1 = json.load(f)
jyson2 = json.load(fe)

print(diff(jyson1, jyson2))
```

EDIT:
Because i have to parse through 2 folders, I think i need 2 for loops with glob like this

```
for f in glob("/folder1/*.json"):
    with open(f) as fe:
        data_old = json.load(fe)

for e in glob("/folder2/*.json"):
    with open(e) as ee:
        data_new = json.load(fe)
```

I struggle to understand how i can use the diff() method here

Comment: Why are you attempting to do it in Python instead of using a diff tool?

Comment: So for each json file you want the diff between each file from both folders  ? What's the schema like of each json file ?

Comment: What was the difficulty when you tried to write a loop?

Comment: @sophros Because I'm a python beginner and wanted to make something useful for myself

Comment: @Manakin The schema is the same for all json files. ID, name, cost etc.

Comment: @mkrieger1I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code snippet from which you can work on. It also only tests for files which are common in both folders (skips files which are missing in one folder for any reason). In contrast to your code snippet you need to work in one not in two for loops:

```py
import os

names1 = os.listdir("folder1") # names of all json files in folder1
names2 = os.listdir("folder2") # names of all json files in folder2
commonnames = set(names1) & set(names2) # set of all file names which are in folder1 and folder2

for filename in commonnames:
  json1 = json.load(open(os.path.join("folder1", filename))
  json2 = json.load(open(os.path.join("folder2", filename))

  print(diff(json1, json2))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i can definitely work with this!